# Problem getting data from DB using DatePicker date

Tags: android, sqlite, android-datepicker

Hey I got a problem here.

I'm trying to retrieve the date from the Database based on Date passed to the method, and it returns the value.

The problem is that, when I try to pass the variable that receives the date, the method that select the data from the DB, returns nothing. (and I print the date variable on the LogCat and it's ok, the date value is correct), but if I pass a String value like this ("1/01/1111") it returns correctly.

here is the method on the activity that get the value and set the text.

```
public void setBasicContent() {

    date = (mMonth + 1) + "/" + mDay + "/" + mYear + " ";
    hpdData = this.hpd.selectDuration(date);
    mDateDisplay.setText(hpdData);

}
```

And here is the selectDuration() method that select the data from the DB based on the date parameter.

Ah, when I pass the variable date in the activity, the code doesn't reach the `if(cursor.moveToFirst())` scope. But I don't know why, because the variable value is completely correctly exactly like a normal string.

```
public String selectDuration(String date) {

    String duration = "";
    Integer value = 0;
    String returnment = "";
    Log.i(TAG, "date to select: " + date);
    Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "duration" },
            "date = ?", new String[] { date }, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Log.i("SELECTDURATION", "inside cursor.moveToFirst()");
            duration = cursor.getString(0);
            value += Integer.parseInt(duration);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        returnment = Integer.toString(value);
    }

    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "valor do returnment: " + returnment);
    return returnment;
}
```

Comment: Hm, difficult to tell what's going on here because I'm not sure what's happening to your string inside of query(). Perhaps try constructing an SQL query manually and pass that into rawQuery() instead? You could then view the exact statement that's being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. It is on the `setBasicContent()` method.

Here is the old method:

```
public void setBasicContent() {

date = (mMonth + 1) + "/" + mDay + "/" + mYear + " ";
hpdData = this.hpd.selectDuration(date);
mDateDisplay.setText(hpdData);
```

}

and here is the new method modified:

```
public void setBasicContent() {

date = (mMonth + 1) + "/" + mDay + "/" + mYear;
hpdData = this.hpd.selectDuration(date);
mDateDisplay.setText(hpdData);
```

}

The problem is on this line:

```
 date = (mMonth + 1) + "/" + mDay + "/" + mYear + " ";
```

If you see, it concatenates an empty character to the date, so in the String will pass the date string with an empty character, which for a String makes the difference. So it must be like this:

```
date = (mMonth + 1) + "/" + mDay + "/" + mYear;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything obviously incorrect in your code, provided your db reference is instantiated ok. If possible, store your dates as integers in the datbase, storing the milliseconds value from date.toTime(). It's then much easier to instantiate a date object from new Date(milliseconds) and you can then format the output according to the locale.

Answer (score 0):

I have written my method of doing this on my blog. I convert to a Calendar object and use getTimeInMillis(). That way you only have to store a 'long' value in the database.

[Storing a DatePicker and TimePicker in SQLite Database](http://www.bytefoundry.co.uk/blog/?p=214)